# Modifying rendered frames before they are displayed on HMD (i.e. filter)?

Tags: windows-mixed-reality

Would like to experiment with fading the display towards black as the pixels get further from the seat spot of the HMD; My natural instinct is for my eyes to track anything that appears to be viewable in the field of view meaning I inevitably look away from the seat spot and spoil the illusion - was thinking if the image faded away then it would be more natural to keep within the sweat spot...

Does WMR provide any way to modify rendered frames before they are output to the displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for post-processing camera effects. It occurs after the camera draws the scene but before the scene is rendered on the screen. If you are developing WMR App via Unity, please see this link for
how to set up the components required to create post-processing effects in your scene: [Post-processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0/manual/index.html)

Besides, complicated  post-processing on HMD devices is not recommended, because it is computationally expensive, and you might have large FPS drop, more information please see [Avoid full-screen effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/performance-recommendations-for-unity#avoid-full-screen-effects)